# Laravel echo server private channel listener is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo

I'm a beginner with laravel-echo and I'm trying to add real time notification to my app using laravel-echo-server, redis and socket.io, but the listener I added is not even called? Did I miss something? it would really be helpful if someone could help me with this.

BaseNotification.php

```
class BaseNotification extends Notification implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $userToNotify;

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('user.' . $this->userToNotify->id);
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }
}
```

laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
    "authHost": "localhost",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "redis"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": ""
}
```

laravel-echo-server logs

```
Channel: private-user.3NnnjV

Event: Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated
```

Client JS listener config

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'socket.io',
        host: `localhost:6001`,
      });

window.Echo.private('user.3NnnjV'')
        .listen('.Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated', (e) => {
        console.log('event notification',e);
      })
```

laravel version: 8.0

Did I miss some configuration above?